# How to replace abort() function in coreData iOS

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am working with CoreData app, As we know while saving a entity or deleting a entity from context we always make this check

```
NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);

    }
```

I too in my app at many places have this code, the commenting by apple says **" Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.**

I am not able to figure few things

1) What message to show to user?

2) Shall I ask the user to send me the error report?

3) Should I use the abort?

Comment: (1) It's up to you. (2) It's up to you. (3) From the comment you yourself posted: "You should not use this function in a shipping application"

Comment: You should have consistent error handling implemented throughout your app. How you do this is up to you. A common way to do this is to implement the error responder chain. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806

Comment: @quellish Error responders are only available in OS X (this post is tagged as iOS)

Comment: Yes, and you can implement the error responder chain on iOS. Example: https://github.com/kemenaran/ios-presentError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Entirely up to you.  Be sure to explain simply that there was a problem and that their data could not be saved.  This kind of situation should be very rare.

2) Also up to you, but most users will not know how to do that.  It would help if you implemented logic to email the error to you inside the app.

Responsible 3) Absolutely not (what is unclear about "You should not use this function in a shipping application"?).  A save failure will not make your application unable to continue since the data will still be available in memory.

Alternate 3) Entirely up to you.  If the app review team catches it, you will be rejected.  This save failure is very unlikely to happen outside of development though.

Comment: Ok, So borrden, as you said if I implement a email logic inside my app, and id user presses cancel instead of sending me email then what should happen ? Whether the app runs as asual or it will crash?

Comment: I can't think of any good reason to crash the app on purpose.  You should continue since no corruption has happened (the save just failed).  It will likely keep failing but it is still better than a crash from a user perspective, I think.  There is nothing more jarring then suddenly seeing the home screen.